# Como recuperar informação da base de dados por id no ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Tenho uma app que estou a desenvolver em `ionic` e `angularjs` estou a usar `routes` e estou a buscar os dados a uma bases de dados num servidor remoto, tenho uma página onde e me listado varias categorias e cada categoria tem um `id` associado da categoria.
O meu problema está em agora ao clicar na categoria mande o id para o php e na próxima pagina me liste os estabelecimentos correspondentes a essa categoria mas não sei como fazer, gostaria de uma ajuda dicas como posso fazer isso.

**Route**

```
.state('app.estabelecimentos', {
  url: "/estabelecimentos/:id",
  views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/estabelecimentos.html",
    controller: 'ListaDistritos'
    //controller: 'CategoriaComer'
  }
 }
})
```

**Listagem das categorías**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="cat_comer in comer">
        <div class="col">
            <a href="#/app/estabelecimentos/{{cat_comer.id}}">
                <div style="background: url(https://www.sabeonde.pt/gtm/anexos/colecoes/{{cat_comer.id_anexo}}.{{cat_comer.tipo}}); border-radius: 6px; height: 200px; background-size: 100% 100%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
                    <div class="texto_categorias">
                        <div class="titulo_estabelecimentos">{{cat_comer.campo_slug}} ESTABELECIMENTOS</div>
                        {{cat_comer.titulo}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Suponha que você tenha o seguinte controller:

```
angular.module('stackoverflow.example',[])
.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

//Rota que possui o JSON que você quer consumir.
var url = 'http://seusite.com.br/estabelecimentos/' + $scope.categoria_id

$http.get(url).
success(function(data) {
    //O parâmetro data é responsável por devolver as informações capturadas pelo servidor no seu banco de dados.
    //Você pode agora setar uma variável com estas informações (suponha que o servidor retorne um objeto Estabelecimento
    $scope.estabelecimento = data.estabelecimento;

    //Caso queira ver a resposta completa do servidor:
    console.log(data)
}).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //É possível tratar os erros dentro desta função.
});

}
```

Fique atento para a importação correta da [dependência $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) na declaração do controller em questão. Sempre que você for utiliza tal dependência, seja em  controller ou services, etc você precisa importar ele corretamente para poder utiliza-lo.

Answer (score 2):

Se você está passando o ID pela rota, basta recuperar da seguinte forma no seu controller.

```
app.controller('ListaDistritos', ['$rootScope', '$http', '$stateParams', function($rootScope, $http, $stateParams) {
   $rootScope.Lista = null;

   $http.post('/RecuperarLista', {id: $routeParams.id})
   .success(function(response){
       $rootScope.Lista = response;
   });
}]);
```

Note que estou recuperando utilizando o `$stateParams` e acessando o campo `'id'` que foi definido na sua rota (`:id`).

**`$routeParams`**

Ao utilizar no seu controle, ele deve retornar um objeto contendo todos os parametros definidos no `state` (rota).

[Referencia](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service).

Também recomendo a leitura no uso do **[ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref)**.

Answer (score 1):

No angular você precisa criar um Service e  injetar o competente $http, ai você chama seu arquivo PHP que deve retornar um JSON =

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/urldoarquivo.php').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   //aqui você recebe o json
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    //Pega os erros
  });
```

Da uma olhada na documentação https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Sim mas como e que eu mando o id da categoria para o php ?

Comment: Você passa como parametro para o $http = `$http.get(user.details_path, {
    params: { user_id: user.id }
});`